Recurring Sales per Product Netsuite
In Netsuite, I will be able to have a saved search or report where I can classify the sale of a product as a "recurring sale", with a specific frequency (monthly, quarterly, bimonthly), and generate an alert or email, when the condition is not true
Thanks for reading me
